# Designing a toilet for autoimmune protection: engineering question

Tags: design, systems-engineering, biomedical-engineering, systems-design, equipment-selection

In autoimmune disorders, when a bacteria enters the body, the immune system resounds, growing, fighting it off, but this immune system growth, due, to the autoimmune disorder, also attacks the person's *meat" cells (the flesh), causing, damage.

For these people, a proper toilet design could be suitable, and life saving.

I am wondering how you could design a toilet for autoimmune disease control.

I was thinking:

- the top part must seal
- when the top part is sealed, not only, does water, flow down, and flush, ... a disinfectant component, gets sprayed, not too parsimoniously, but thoroughly, throughout all surfaces (perhaps, a robotic component, is at play
- the flushed stuff, goes, into an atrium, before it is discarded, where bacteria are collected (what, do they eat?). Bacteria, are, through, biological technology, septated, according to type.

They are then analyzed, while sealed (this way they do not come into contact with the autoimmune person).

Perhaps, there is an adjecent room, where they can be viewed.

The room has microscope facility, with the bacteria on the other side of the wall (seen, through glass, and the glass is cleaned automatically behind the wall, before, the analysis).

- A seriate air duct is provided, that, drives air out, with tubes extending in the outside of the household, till a drainage facility.

This ensures even outside air is not contaminated.

The air duct, ensures, the toilet can be properly, AND FULLY sealed, before flushing.

This means bacteria do not flow out during a flush onto clothes and exposed body parts like hands and face.

Also, because, these can be washed (more or less, fully), and some people forget.

But clothes cannot be washed (not, immediately).

They could be changed.

How would you design such a system from an engineering perspective?

Why don't toilets, fully seal?

Thanks.

Comment: Those toilets used by customs? with an atmospheric system to draw air out of the toilet.

Comment: "*Why don't toilets, fully seal?*" Because that would impede airflow which would impede water egress. You would need to provide a high air-flow vent somehow.

Comment: Would that be expensive? Could you post an answer with a detailed, design?

Comment: Alternatively, one could design a toilet with a wire which could be wired behind walls or visibly as a protuberance in a metal sheath that could link the toilet (and its flushing), visually, to the toilet flush button, away from the toilet (either, in the same room (for example, by the door entrance)), or, even, via a hole linking toiletroom inside and toiletroom outside, with the wire passing through, so you could flush on the outside, with, the toiletroom door closed (so that germs from the toilet air would not come into contact with you at all).

Comment: Not sure what this would entail from an electrical point of view

Comment: Would be nice, in, advanced, buildings, if the toilet button could have a QR code, on the side (or, better, somewhere, within the bathroom, it, better, outside) which could scan with your phone, to connect your phone, and, flush, from your phone.

Comment: Not particularly useful, because, you need to wash your hands, before flushing, anyways, so an exterior button would do, but, again, this button may be dirty. Why not avoid contanination by locating the button on your phone. If a person was on the toilet, flushing from the outside via a button could be a problem for the person's butt, getting wet (by mistake or prank). Because someone could forget to flush, and flush at a later time, even from bed, using their Android phone. Problematic, if the toilet overreaps, and you're not there, to see it (and clean, and fix).

Comment: Hope my input, is, useful, in designing a good toilet. You could have a mechanism to disable the outside flushing button while the person was in. Not sure what that would be. You could simply have a sensor, inside the entrance, to detect that the person enteted, and, disable the circuit when the person goes in, and passes the sensor, and enable the flushing circuit back when the person goes out. It could even keep track of the person count (people in the toiletroom), on a stack. Last person or would have to flush.

Comment: By using the phone, you would only get dirty with the sink tap (sink could be tapless and use a sensor), and not with the phone button for flushing (in alternative, even better, even the toilet-fkushing button on the outside could be a sensor. This would eliminate the need to use your phone to flush, to avoid getting dirty from the flushing button (with toilet room germs).